# Multiple Replication Agents Not working in Round robin manner in AEM/CQ

Tags: content-management-system, aem

We have setup two replication agents on our AEM enviornment where there is one author which replicates to two publish servers using the two replication agents.

We analyze the replication.log file for few days and we have found that sometimes, the author replicates to both the replication agents in a round-robin fashion i.e. out of many pages added to the queue, each page is replication to one publish and then other publish and then author moves to another page in queue. This is ideal behaviour. 
But few times, the author first starts to replicate everything on one publish server first and replicated everything there and then replicates the content to other publish which cause a delay to 2-5 mins in replication between two publishers and the content is NOT same on both publishers during that time.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: What version of AEM? It sounds like you are doing heavy replication if it takes 2-5 minutes, How many things, pages, DAM assets? Are you using batch mode? It's certainly not normal for round-robin-like behaviour with multiple independent queues that should run in parallel.

Comment: 2-5 mins is an example when we do heavy replication like 500 pages. But there is usually a difference between replication complete times on botht he publish servers. They are not usually round-robin, so we usually get a different content on both publishers for that time, lets say even if it is for a minute.